# Unix Cron for running job on 1st weekday

Tags: cron

Can someone help mw with the cron expression for running job on 1st weekday??

Is it possible in simple unix crontab?

Answer (score 0):

If your week start on Monday and you want to run script every monday you should use something like (suppose you run your script at 22h 00m)

```
0 22 * * 1 /path/to/script
```

If you want to run the script first work day of month and your week start on Monday you can try something like:

```
0 22 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 * * /path/to/script
```

and add on the begin of the script this:

```
if [ "$(date +%u) -ne 1 ] 
then exit
fi
```

this will end the script if you run it on day of week which is not Monday